# SQL query, count and group by

Tags: sql

If I have data like this:

| Key | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dan |
| 2 | Tom |
| 3 | Jon |
| 4 | Tom |
| 5 | Sam |
| 6 | Dan |

What is the SQL query to bring back the records where `Name` is repeated 2 or more times?

So the result I would want is

| Tom |
| --- |
| Dan |

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Couldn't be simpler...

```sql
Select Name, Count(Name) As Count 
    From Table
    Group By Name
    Having Count(Name) > 1
    Order By Count(Name) Desc
```

This could also be extended to delete duplicates:

```sql
Delete From Table
Where Key In (
    Select Max(Key)
        From Table
        Group By Name
        Having Count(Name) > 1
    )
```

Comment: For delete, you should leave only the Min(key) and delete other entries. Query should be modified as "...where Key NOT IN ( select Min(Key) ...."

Answer (score 4):

```
select name from table group by name having count(name) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This could also be accomplished by joining the table with itself,

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name
FROM    tbl t1
        INNER JOIN tbl t2
        ON      t1.name = t2.name
WHERE   t1.key         != t2.key;
```